# What's the best way to create recurring payments of variable amount in Stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an online club which needs to invoice its users each month. Recurring payments looks great for this, however they are based on "Plans" where I set up different defaults and the user subscribes to a plan. 
My users can pay anything between $2 and $200 and those amounts might vary depending on the month since it's recurring products they're buying.

Does anyone have any good suggestions on how I can to this in Stripe? So far all i've come up with is invoicing & account balance. Which means shoehorning the user into a subscription plan that is near their payment and then adding a negative or positive balance to cover the rest. However I'm certain this isn't the best way (in fact. I think it's a really bad way)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you are looking for metered billing options: https://support.stripe.com/questions/metered-subscription-billing

This mentions the account balance and invoicing method.

There is also another method described here: https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-can-i-create-plans-that-dont-have-a-fixed-price

> One approach is to create a plan for your users valued at $1/month (100 cents). When subscribing the customer to the plan, you can modify the amount the customer will owe by setting the quantity value. This method gives your users the ability to define how much they will pay each month, to the full dollar amount.
>
> For example, a customer subscribed to a $1/month plan at a quantity of 100 will result in a $100 charge every billing cycle.
>
> If you want a greater level of flexibility in your plans, you could create a $0.01 plan (1 cent). Though keep in mind that a customer won't be charged for an invoice under $0.50; the amount will roll over to their next invoice.